# Remote Powershell Session fails when executed from PHP, works when executed in commandline

Tags: php, powershell

I'm working on a setup where a few PHP files need to get data through remote powershell. My PHP runs on Linux and I installed powershell on here. This works fine as when in command line I can perfectly use all its functionality and run commands.

I created a PowerShell script `VMData.ps1` which runs fine when executed in command line - see below.

```
www@server:~# pwsh /www/wwwroot/site/PowerShell/VMData.ps1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763
Platform                       Win32NT
PSVersion                      7.3.3
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.3
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

Then I run this script in php using the following:

```php
$output = shell_exec('pwsh /PowerShell/VMData.ps1 2>&1');
```

Sadly doing so gives me an error with very little information:

```
New-PSSession: /www/wwwroot/site/PowerShell/VMData.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  $session=New-PSSession -hostname "192.168.1.12" -username "Administra …
     |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | [192.168.1.12] An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A
     | remote session might have ended.
Invoke-Command: /www/wwwroot/site/PowerShell/VMData.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  Invoke-Command $session -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable}
     |                 ~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or
     | empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
     | command again.
```

The user that is used by the PHP is the same as the one that i use to execute the script in the command line. An SSH Public & Private key is set up to establish the connection without requiring a password.

The script it runs:

```
$t="test"
$session=New-PSSession -hostname "192.168.1.12" -username "Administrator"
Invoke-Command $session -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable}
```

Does anyone know why it's failing when executed by php, but runs fine when executed in putty (aka command line) when logged in as the same user? (As confirmed by printing whoami)

Comment: It might help to take the time to format the error message so it's readable.

Comment: @miken32 https://hastebin.com/share/dewesoyamo.bash ill update post when able